# The disadvantage of editing source that build in react.js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-mvc, next.js

I'm initializing web project follow this tool

- Backend : java by using Spring MVC framework
- frontend : react.js by using next.js framework

Frontend source is inside backend and when I build frontend i placed it inside webapp so the structure of project look like this.

- root

  - react

    - frontend
  - src

    - main

      - java

        - controller
      - resources
      - web app

        - build (react build will go here!)

From backend can make a right call to frontend. But there are a static resources which must be used and page cannot find them.

So I changed src path in html file (I changed it in folder "build/") then page can find resources. for example

- before in index.html

  ```
  <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/commons.a979bd194c5739a7c69d.js" as="script" />
  <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/runtime/main-eb82511d0817e1061fd2.js" as="script" />
  ```
- after in index.html

  ```
  <link rel="preload" href="/myWeb/build/_next/static/chunks/commons.a979bd194c5739a7c69d.js" as="script" />
  <link rel="preload" href="/myWeb/build/_next/static/runtime/main-eb82511d0817e1061fd2.js" as="script" />
  ```

My Question is: Is there a real disadvantage from what I did?

Comment: Please help, I would appreciate so much.